# How do I deploy my express web app on nginx web server using docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have been trying to deploy my express web application to nginx web server.

This is my directory structure.

```
express-app 
     frontend 
         public
             /*all resources, images etc*/
         src 
             /*all js files*/
         views 
             /*html files*/
         package.json
         index.js //server file
         Dockerfile //image for front end
     backend  
         src
             server.js
         package.json
         Dockerfile //image for backend
     proxy
         Dockerfile //??? 
         proxy.conf //???
     docker-compose.yml
```

I have successfully dockerised my application and it works fine. But i am little confused in how do i create Dockerfile for nginx and proxy.nginx so that nginx could be used as a web server for my application. The Dockerfiles for frontend and backend work.

Dockerfile for front end:

```
FROM node:carbon
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/frontend
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/frontend
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install && npm install gulp -g
# Bundle app source
COPY . .
CMD ["gulp","sass","js-global","js-pages"]
EXPOSE 8081
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Dockerfile for backend:

```
FROM node:carbon  
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app    
# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
ENV MONGODB_URL=mongodb://mongo/db3
ENV BACKEND_HOST_PATH=http://localhost:5000/
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I am using docker for windows.
How do I make a dockerfile and conf file for nginx so that it acts as a web server for my application?

Comment: Do you want Nginx to sit between frontend and backend to handle communication between FE and BE (or multiple BE's) ? Or do you need Nginx to accept all incoming requests, forward them to FE (assuming FE and BE are able to communicate without Nginx) ?

Comment: Yes. I want nginx to accept all incoming requests, FE and BE are separately running on different servers and communicating with each other.

Comment: Check the `docker-compose` and `nginx.conf` files at http://anandmanisankar.com/posts/docker-container-nginx-node-redis-example/

Answer (score 0):

I think there is two way.

first,
simple nginx isn't dockernize.
You setup nginx in docker host.
and just nginx proxy.

```
#front
location / { 
        proxy_pass http://localhost: 8081;
}  

#backend
location / { 
        proxy_pass http://localhost: 8081;
}
```

second,
if you want to using dockernize about nginx.

```
docker network create test
docker run --name nginx --network=test
docker run --name front --network=test
docker run --name backend --network=test
```

you excute above command.
nginx container connect front, backend by name;
this is like hosts file.

Do you understand?
Did I understand what do you want?